# Cant create instance of model class in custom ConsoleCommand Yii

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, command-line-interface

I try to create instance of certain model in console command, but first I getting errors about that Yii could not find model class, then I do this

```
Yii::import('application.models.*');
```

, and now I get new this error

```
'The table "{{user}}" for active record class "User" cannot be found in the database.'
```

In database table called tbl_user. 
I try to search on another related topics but I didnt find the solution for this problem. 
Here is [link to my model class](https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/a202bf144bf0896ea33f) .

Here is the [link to my config file](https://gist.github.com/NovikovViktor/ec1da72be69de9feecff)
I think, the problem not in config file because migrations command works properly.

Comment: have you created a separate config file like main.php for console command?

Comment: @ThinkDifferent, I update post, look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your db config (console file)

```
"tablePrefix"=>"tbl_"
```